# Haskell MultiParamTypeClasses and UndecidableInstances

Tags: haskell, typeclass, type-systems

I'm new to Haskell and just playing around awhile.

I have written a lightweight OOP simulation:

```
 --OOP.hs
 {-# LANGUAGE MultiParamTypeClasses, FlexibleInstances, UndecidableInstances, ScopedTypeVariables, FunctionalDependencies #-}

module OOP where 
class Provides obj iface where
    provide::obj->iface
    (#>)::obj->(iface->a)->a
    o #> meth = meth $ provide o

class Instance cls obj | obj -> cls where
    classOf::obj->cls

class Implements cls iface where
    implement::(Instance cls obj)=>cls->obj->iface

instance (Instance cls obj, Implements cls iface)=>Provides obj iface where
    provide x = implement (classOf x::cls) x
```

using it like:

```
 --main.hs
 {-# LANGUAGE MultiParamTypeClasses #-}

import OOP
data I1 = I1
getI1::I1->String
getI1 i1 = "Interface 1"

data I2 = I2
getI2::I2->String
getI2 i2 = "Interface 2"


data C = C


instance Implements C I1 where
    implement C o = I1

instance Implements C I2 where
    implement C o = I2

data O = O
instance Instance C O where
    classOf o = C

main = do
    putStrLn (O #> getI1)
    putStrLn (O #> getI2)
```

I read that `UndecidableInstances` feature is pretty inconvenient and can lead to [stack overflows](https://stackoverflow.com/) in the compiler. So I have two questions.

1. Could this code be improved, preserving ease of use and `1 to N` relations between instance and class data types as well as between interface and class?
2. Could be the similar logic implemented with Single Param Type Classes?

Comment: It can't be repeated often enough that writing OO in Haskell is a bad idea, especially for beginners... but I think you know that already. The way you approach it actually looks quite interesting. — There's in fact not much bad about `UndecidableInstances`; anything bad that could happen will happen during compilation, so it's pretty safe.

Comment: What's the difference between a class and an interface in your system? (Except you restrict, arbitrarily it seems, class inheritance to be single inheritance).

Comment: @leftaroundabout I'm not intend this for practical use, although i'm under impression of [this article](http://www.haskellforall.com/2013/02/you-could-have-invented-comonads.html). Main idea is to understand haskell approaches to define proper type architecture and OOP is just domain i'm familiar with.

Comment: Typically the domain being modeled won't be done using type classes. MPTCs without fundeps have bad inference properties. Instead of making your types simple and storing information in the typeclasses, it's usually more common place to make that stuff explicit and represent it in the types as records. The compiler makes that transformation for you anyway (that's how TCs are implemented) but you won't have inference woes.

Comment: "I'm new to metalwork and I'm having trouble whilst making a whittling knife that works well." I hear this kind of problem too much. Master metalwork on its own terms first. Leave woodwork behind for now. Your lathe skills are transferrable, but there's a reason most metalworkers don't carve.

Comment: The article you link to,  [Gabriel Gonzalez' Comonads are Objects](http://www.haskellforall.com/2013/02/you-could-have-invented-comonads.html) is a good article about comonads, but you seem to have diverged significantly from that, and you should be aware that comonads are not Java in a Haskell box.

Comment: @chunksOf50 I'm absolutely aware of it. I'm not trying to transform Haskell code to OCaml code. OOP terms here are insignificant. And i would very appreciate if you won't treat me like some functional programming renegate for those. 
Main trouble is not "how to code in Haskell like in Java". But how to make code more plain preserving type relations.

Comment: @J.Abrahamson make good point here. But i just can not implement his thoughts due to insufficient understanding of base things.

Comment: @Odomontois OK, if I now understand you correctly, there are two approaches you might benefit from. One is Type Families, where you can program with types in a much more functional way. I find that a significant proportion of the time, `{-# LANGUAGE MultiParamTypeClasses, FunctionalDependencies #-}` with `class MPFD a b | a -> b` is better off as `{-# LANGUAGE TypeFamilies #-}` with `class TF a where B a :: *`. At the moment you're implementing a OO paradigm using a FP language and Logic Programming at the type level. Type Families removes one paradigm, and uses functions at the type level.

Comment: The second is moving your typeclass logic down from the type system to ordinary functions, which is what J.Abrahamson is referring to. My favourite introduction to that replacement is [Luke Palmer's alternative to Existential Typeclasses](http://lukepalmer.wordpress.com/2010/01/24/haskell-antipattern-existential-typeclass/). You're not using existential typeclasses, but the principal of moving logic out of the type system and into functions and records is sound. You might accidentally end up reifying everything, but it's worth looking into.

Comment: Though it's a fairly advanced paper, [Jeremy Gibbon's *Unfolding Abstract Datatypes*](http://www.cs.ox.ac.uk/jeremy.gibbons/publications/adt.pdf) is easily the best intro to how to think about OO in Haskell I know of.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your use of undecidable instances in this case is fine.

```
instance (Instance cls obj, Implements cls iface)=>Provides obj iface where
```

is undecidable because you might have an instance for `Instance` or `Implements` that in turn relies on `Provides` causing a loop.

However, in this case, you don't need the `Provides` class at all, because you only give an implementation of it in terms of methods from your other two classes!

You could instead pull `provides` and `#>` out to be top level functions with the appropriate `Instance` and `Implements` constraints and you would lose nothing, and avoid the need for the undecidable instance.

You do need/want MPTCs for this however, and that's fine...